# Почему в коде JavaScript не работает else?

Tags: javascript, html, if, change

Только начал изучение JS и не могу понять почему в моем коде видимо "не работает" else...
В результате выполнения кода хотел бы чтобы при вводе текста в input текст дублировался ниже. Если же пользователь не ввел текст то выводилась бы строка с соответствующей надписью... Проверку на наличие текста в input решил проводить с помощью .length.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <input type="text" name="string">
  <p>Дублирую: <span class="result"></span></p>

  <script>
    strElement = document.querySelector('[name="string"]');
    resElement = document.querySelector(".result");

    strElement.addEventListener("change", function() {
        if (strElement.length != 0) {
            resElement.textContent = strElement.value;
        } else {
            resElement.textContent = "Вы ничего не ввели...";
        }
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: `strElement` — это объект `HTMLInputElement`, а у таких объектов не бывает свойства `length`, а значит `strElement.length` это undefined, а undefined всегда не равен нулю, поэтому это условие if всегда выполняет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заменить

```
strElement.length != 0
```

на

```
strElement.value.length != 0
```

---

Кстати, вместо события `change` можно (удобнее) использовать событие `input`

Comment: Хахах, спасибо) Долго бы я еще ответ проискал)

Comment: Пожалуйста.  Галочку рядом с ответом тык)) ...........Кстати, вместо события `change` можно (удобнее) использовать событие `input`